# Issue around Canonicalizing the contents of a soap attachment(a xml file) before calculating digest for the purpose of signing (Web Service Security)

Tags: java, spring, web-services, security

Posting this question after not finding a similar question/answer elsewhere.

I'm using Spring(3) Web Services on Java 7.
I have a soap message with one attachment having xml contents and I need to **send** it across, after applying security by canonicalizing the attachment(a xml file) xml contents BEFORE calculating the digest of the attachment contents. Calculated digest will eventually be signed and included in the soap message header as in the typical scenario.

My spring bean configuration is as follows. (Removed unrelated beans for clarity)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

  <sws:annotation-driven/>
  
  <bean id="fvsOutInterceptor" class="my.package.FvsOutInterceptor"/>

  <bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
      <constructor-arg ref="messageFactory"/>
      <property name="interceptors">
          <list>
              <ref bean="fvsOutInterceptor"/>
          </list>
      </property>
      <property name="messageSender" ref="httpMessageSender"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">
    <property name="soapVersion">
      <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapVersion.SOAP_12"/>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="httpMessageSender" class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender"/>

  <bean id="messageSender" class="my.package.SoapMessageSender"/>

  <bean id="xwssInterceptor" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.XwsSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="policyConfiguration" value="classpath:spring/policy/signatureOnlySecurityPolicy.xml"/>
    <property name="callbackHandlers">
      <list>
        <ref bean="keyStoreHandler"/>
        <ref bean="authenticationHandler"/>
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="keyStoreHandler" class="my.package.RemoteKeyStoreCallbackHandler"/>

  <bean id="authenticationHandler" class="my.package.WssPasswordCallbackHandler"/>  

</beans>
```

The actual FvsOutInterceptor bean defined above is as follows.

```js
package my.package;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceClientException;
import org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceFaultException;
import org.springframework.ws.client.support.interceptor.ClientInterceptor;
import org.springframework.ws.context.MessageContext;
import org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage;
import org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.XwsSecurityInterceptor;

import javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;

public class FvsOutInterceptor implements ClientInterceptor {

    @Autowired
    protected XwsSecurityInterceptor xwsSecurityInterceptor;

    @Autowired
    private FvsRemoteKeyStoreCallbackHandler fvsKeyStoreHandler;

    @Override
    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = getSaajRequestFrom(messageContext);

        return processFvsEbms3Request(soapMessage, messageContext);
    }

    private boolean processFvsEbms3Request(SOAPMessage soapMessage, MessageContext messageContext) {
        insertSAMLTokenIntoWebServiceSecurityHeader(soapMessage);
        return applySecurityPolicyTo(messageContext);
    }

    private boolean applySecurityPolicyTo(MessageContext messageContext) {
        try {
            synchronized (xwsSecurityInterceptor) {
                xwsSecurityInterceptor.setPolicyConfiguration(new ClassPathResource
                        ("spring/policy/fvsEbms3SecurityPolicy.xml"));
                xwsSecurityInterceptor.setCallbackHandlers(new CallbackHandler[]{fvsKeyStoreHandler});
                xwsSecurityInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet();
                return xwsSecurityInterceptor.handleRequest(messageContext);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new WebServiceFaultException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
        return true;
    }

    private SOAPMessage getSaajRequestFrom(MessageContext messageContext) {
        return ((SaajSoapMessage) messageContext.getRequest()).getSaajMessage();
    }

    private void insertSAMLTokenIntoWebServiceSecurityHeader(SOAPMessage soapMessage) {
        // Code for adding a saml token into security header comes here. (Code removed for clarity)
    }
}
```

The fvsEbms3SecurityPolicy.xml security policy configuration file used above is as follows.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xwss:SecurityConfiguration xmlns:xwss="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/xwss/config" dumpMessages="true" retainSecurityHeader="true">
  <xwss:Sign includeTimestamp="false">
    <xwss:X509Token keyReferenceType="Direct" />
    <xwss:SignatureTarget type="qname" value="{urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion}EncryptedAssertion">
      <xwss:Transform algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
    </xwss:SignatureTarget>
    <xwss:SignatureTarget type="qname" value="{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ebxml-msg/ebms/v3.0/ns/core/200704/}Messaging">
      <xwss:Transform algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
    </xwss:SignatureTarget>
    <xwss:SignatureTarget type="qname" value="SOAP-BODY">
      <xwss:Transform algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
    </xwss:SignatureTarget>
    <xwss:SignatureTarget type="uri" value="cid:*">
      <xwss:Transform algorithm="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-SwAProfile-1.1#Attachment-Content-Signature-Transform">
        <xwss:AlgorithmParameter name="CanonicalizationMethod" value="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
      </xwss:Transform>
    </xwss:SignatureTarget>
  </xwss:Sign>
</xwss:SecurityConfiguration>
```

I have iteratively changed and retried the attachment related element in the policy file (which is extracted and shown below) to get c14n triggered before digest is calculated, but failed with no luck.

```html
<xwss:SignatureTarget type="uri" value="cid:*">
  <xwss:Transform algorithm="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-SwAProfile-1.1#Attachment-Content-Signature-Transform">
    <xwss:AlgorithmParameter name="CanonicalizationMethod" value="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
  </xwss:Transform>
</xwss:SignatureTarget>
```

The entire setup works just fine in runtime, except attachment's c14n not triggering before digest calculation - which I'm struggling.

Any help to resolve my issue is highly appreciated. (In case, if you need more info, please let know)  Thank you!

Comment: Which is it, you either use Spring Web Services or the Metro (JAX-WS) stuff using both isn't an option. So what is it you are using. Show your web service implementation and your configuration. Currently there is too little information and too much confusing information in your question.

Comment: Tks a lot for reaching out for me. I have updated the question with more info, as you requested. The application uses spring web services, and not metro. You are right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it myself. Actually, it's nothing to do with the code. Code works and c14n kicks in before calculating digest.
The issue was with my misunderstanding that it didn't c14n, where as it actually did.

How it happened is like this. The recipient of my soap message calculated the soap attachment digest different to the one I calculated. Hence, I assumed the difference is due to recipient properly doing c14n, where as I'm not. What has actually happened is that the recipient has chosen a c14n algorithm(for mime content-type "text/plain") which is different from the c14n algorithm I chose(for mime content-type "text/xml"). Once I and the recipient started using the same c14n algorithm, the resulting digest calculated to be the same.

Hope this post helps somebody else!